# Research with intuition's with proof's or without proof's

Tags: research-process, presentation

I am currently a PhD student (after mid stage) working in computational mathematics. I am currently writing and solving a couple of research problems. I feel very excited whenever I get new results, but when someone  counters my solution, I feel very uncomfortable because of the time and energy I have invested in the work. Uncomfortable just means sweating a bit  or trying to prove that my idea or claim is true. Whenever someone tells me that it is wrong, I admit it but start a new line with "but" and trying to give an explanation. I am aware that some of my past results have been wrong but some of them were right also till now the ratio is 70:30 (right/wrong). I am an intuitive person, many things I have come up with till now come from my intuition after spending months on single theorem/proof. Although I always try to come up with proofs also, but sometimes I fail to give the proof. There were times when I come up with new claims without complete proof, but me and my supervisor were not able to prove that claim wrong. My way of working is like this, I read a theorem try to prove on my own without looking the research paper.

I discuss the proof with my senior and supervisor multiple times. I try to modify the proof for many time for some cases so that it can be used in computational sense. In this time I try to think in the shower, while walking etc. During this process I develop an intuition about the theorem I am reading. After that I will be claiming something not very out of blue but something which will be helpful in computational mathematics. Then I try to formalise it by writing its proof (this seems very tough to me).

**Question :** Research with intuition, with proof also, but sometimes without proof also. Is this a right way to do research?

Comment: Are you really asking about _research_ without proof, or _published research_ without proof? Even the most die-hard formalist has the former; a lack of proof just makes their research unfinished, not invalid.

Comment: @JeffE I mean research with not a clear proof.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Intuition in mathematics is a good thing. In a researcher it is an essential thing as it leads you to things that *might* be true and *interesting* ideas that are worth pursuing.

However, there is no substitute for correct proof. Proof is what tells you what *is true* and sets a foundation for those future researches. If you write a paper asserting that something is true but don't supply a *correct* proof, it is unlikely to be accepted. Your question seems to imply that you may be incorrectly judging the correctness of some of your proofs. You will need to work on that. An incorrect proof hardly ever has any value. Especially if it claims to prove something that isn't so.

A paper that proposed unanswered questions that were interesting would be worthwhile and it has been done a few times. In those situations, however, it was clear that the problems were hard, the solutions unknown, and even that the correct attack on the problem was eluding mathematicians.

Answer (score 1):

Having some results without proof is fine. Generally speaking, a proof is simply an "ironclad" argument that some general truth holds. However, it may not be the only one, nor is it something to always strive for. The classic example would be that one often proves that some problem X is NP-hard. This does not mean that research on X should stop until we resolve P=NP. It is often just a first step, and many people in more applied mathematical disciplines (e.g. AI and ML related) don't even bother with a formal proof. I have seen interesting applied mathematical works where the mathematical proofs were not the main thing.

The question you should be asking yourself is: what makes my argument compelling? Why should people believe my claims?

If your only answer is a wrong proof, then it should come as no surprise that no one buys into your claims (especially if your hypothesis contradicts known results). You can show that your claim holds empirically on data (if the data is sufficiently interesting, and not just some simulations you cooked up on your laptop), or that it is supported by other known results. You can discuss consequences of your claim (if it were true, then something interesting happens). These are all very valid avenues to pursue, and could help support an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical intuition is virtually necessary for inventing new useful properties, but proofs are equally important, since the results have to be correct. I would suggest two lines how you can proceed:

1) You have an intuition that something must hold but you haven't been able to prove or disprove it. If possible, make a computer program that tests your property systematically (generates values or tests with values from some data). If the result always holds in comprehensive experiments, you can sell it as a "thesis". You may also find out that the property holds only approximately and evaluate how large errors are. In this case, you may try to prove that there is an approximation with certain error bounds.

2) Try to combine your intuition with proving! Try different proof techniques. Change some of your assumptions and test if you manage to finish the proof first with more restrictions. It may also turn out that in practice, the result is equally useful even if you had made some additional assumptions. Identify which subproperties would enable you to prove the final result and try to prove them first. If you get stuck and begin to doubt your intuition, try to invent counter-examples or check what would happen if you assume an opposite proposition.

Additional hints:

- Keep also record on all small properties you have managed to prove during your adventure, since you may need them later.
- In the first trial, don't care if your proof is very long. You can invent more elegant and shorter proofs later, when you just know that something is provable.
- To check your proofs, do them again from scratch. If your original proof contained errors (e.g. typos), you probably can't repeat it again.
- Since PhD project lasts only a few years, don't try to take any lifelong challenges. Prove what you can in a reasonable amount of time and utilize those results. You can always invent extensions later.